# Mono.Cecil AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(): No symbol found for file

Tags: c#, .net, cil, mono.cecil

I am using Mono.Cecil 0.10.3.0, the latest version from nuget.

This line:

```
var ad = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"C:\path\to\my\library.dll", new ReaderParameters { ReadSymbols = true });
```

throws exception:

```
Mono.Cecil.Cil.SymbolsNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=No symbol found for file: C:\path\to\my\library.dll
  Source=Mono.Cecil
  StackTrace:
       at Mono.Cecil.Cil.DefaultSymbolReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, String fileName)
       at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
       at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
       at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
       at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
```

What does this error mean?  Is it not finding library.pdb?  Because the .pdb file exists.

Here's another strange this about this issue.  The ReadAssembly() call will work fine in one version of the code set, but then I will create a new branch of code in git, and try the same line in the new branch, and it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help you, and I have never used this personally, but I looked through the [code here](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/ab5075b3a885ffd5bee5d347b79ce71aabeb32d1/Mono.Cecil.Cil/Symbols.cs) and commented it for your amusement.

```
static void ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
{
   var symbol_reader_provider = parameters.SymbolReaderProvider;

   if (symbol_reader_provider == null && parameters.ReadSymbols)
      symbol_reader_provider = new DefaultSymbolReaderProvider(); // we get here

   if (symbol_reader_provider != null)
   {
      module.SymbolReaderProvider = symbol_reader_provider;

      var reader = parameters.SymbolStream != null
                      ? symbol_reader_provider.GetSymbolReader(module, parameters.SymbolStream)
                      : symbol_reader_provider.GetSymbolReader(module, module.FileName); // we get here

      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Implementation of `GetSymbolReader`

```
public ISymbolReader GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, string fileName)
{

   ...

   // this just changes the extension
   var pdb_file_name = Mixin.GetPdbFileName(fileName);

   // this should be true
   if (File.Exists(pdb_file_name))
   {
      if (Mixin.IsPortablePdb(Mixin.GetPdbFileName(fileName)))
         return new PortablePdbReaderProvider().GetSymbolReader(module, fileName);

      try
      {
         return SymbolProvider.GetReaderProvider(SymbolKind.NativePdb).GetSymbolReader(module, fileName);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
         // We might not include support for native pdbs.
      }
   }

   // can't find the pdb file, your error
   if (throw_if_no_symbol)
      throw new SymbolsNotFoundException(string.Format("No symbol found for file: {0}", fileName));

   return null;
}
```

Definition of `GetPdbFileName`

```
public static string GetPdbFileName(string assemblyFileName)
{
   return Path.ChangeExtension(assemblyFileName, ".pdb");
}
```

So as you can see, something is amiss here. All this code does is

1. Change the extension of your file name to look for the *PBD*,
2. Checks if it the *PBD* file exists,
3. If not, throws the exception you are getting

I think you need to double check everything, also note, the

```
// We might not include support for native pdbs.
```

It's the only other way this error can throw.